# Divs too wide when hiding/showing

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts, hide, html

I have two divs that contain two other divs each. One containing DIV's display is set to none. I have a button that toggles the containing DIVs so I can alternately hide/show the containing div and thus the two divs inside. The inside DIVs are set the 49% width, floated left/right. Problem I have is the fist time the visible DIV is hidden and the hidden one displayed the inside two divs are way too wide. If I resize the width of the browser just a tiny bit with my mouse they are the desired size and any time I toggle the visibility from here on out all is fine. If I reload the page it is wrong on the first toggle. Works the same in IE 10 and Chrome so don't think a browser issue.

The inner two divs both contain high charts that are generated and rendered to the inner divs I want them to be side by side and almost (99%) the width of my page.

Here is snipped of my DIVs to be hidden and shown that contain the inner DIVs with highcharts

```
    <div id="highChartsNG" style="width:99%;display:none;">
        <div id="FillRateHigh" style="border:2px solid black;width:49%;float:left;"></div>
        <div id="WaitTimeHigh"style="border:2px solid black;width:49%;float:right;"></div>               
    </div>                            
     <div id="LowChartsPEAK" style="width:99%">  
        <div id="FillRateLow" style="border:2px solid black;width:49%;float:left;"></div>
        <div id="WaitTimeLow"style="border:2px solid black;width:49%;float:right;" ></div>             
     </div>
```

This is a snippet of the javascript function I call on a button click to toggle on/off on the display of two containing DIVs

```
document.getElementById("highChartsNG").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("LowChartsPEAK").style.display = "block";
```

Fiddle showing problem, see comment of mine below on how to reproduce http://jsfiddle.net/rplace/UTTz4/1/

Comment: try with setting width to 80% or as you like.

Comment: You can try to hide and show the inner divs, that will refresh there sizes.

Comment: ^^ Neither of those worked. I was actually hiding/showing the inner divs originally without the containing DIVs around them - same result. Either way resizing or hiding/showing inner divs doesn't help.

Comment: Maybe the problem is the pixel borders vs. %-based widths? What happens when you remove the borders? Or perhaps you need to set a `clearFix div` underneath the floated items?

Comment: Unable to reproduce http://jsbin.com/EDuMOYI/1

Comment: Here is a fiddle that shows you the problem. Run it and you will see two graphs side by side with nice border all around and evenly spaced. Click the "toggle graphs" button and two new graphs will show up but they will be slightly larger and not look "right". If you resize the browser a bit smaller they will render correctly.http://jsfiddle.net/rplace/UTTz4/1/

Comment: @Tyblitz I tried removing the borders no luck, same problem. Thanks for any and all help, this has me puzzled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after hours of searching I finally found the problem (I think). I was determined to find the solution =).

The problem is multiple-fold.

1. The first problem was the `display:none;` property on the second chartcontainer. For some reason the widths calculated for the charts and their containers were incorrect for the hidden div. So I removed the property from the HTML, and instead hid it dynamically with `document.getElementById("LowChartsPEAK").style.display = "none";` in the JS right after the chart rendering functions. If you do this, your SVG's will fit your containers already, although the last one has a slight shift.
2. Apparently HighChart doesn't like percentage-based parent containers. When you go to [your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UTTz4/4/) , run the fiddle with both:

```
 <div id="wrapper" style="width: 800px;">
 <div id="wrapper" style="width: 100%;">
```

Open the console and check the results (container name - SVG width - container width). When the wrapper is given a pixel width, all container widths are equal (as it should be). Now check the wrapper with percentage width: your last SVG will be about 6 to 20 pixels smaller. The only solution I have found for eliminating that small shift in the last container, is that somewhere a top container must have a pixel-width.

**EDIT:** pt's and em's also work. It's only % that causes problems

Answer (score 0):

If you are hiding DIV, you should be aware that browser won't calculate %-based widths with display:none. Then if browser won;t calculate DIV, then also Highcharts are not able to do it ;)

Check this [FAQ](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/frequently-asked-questions#jquery-ui-tab) - when showing chart update his size or call `reflow()`.